# Is a csv file to store image path and class neccessary for image classification?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, multiclass-classification

I just get my hand-on a basic deep-learning project. I am working on multi-class image classification project with e-commerce dataset. I am not sure whether by storing training images in sub-folder and name the sub-folders as class/category of images is sufficient, or should I have the csv file with image path , image class/category and other meta-data too. Thanks in advance for any input.